Referencing a dependency in Gradle where the module and artifact name differ
I’m trying to retrieve dependencies in Gradle that were published to an Artifactory repository long ago with Ant scripts. In the old Ant Ivy files, their module names differ from the artifact names. The result is that, for example, in Artifactory there might be a folder called “api” with version 1.0 of the api dependency. Under the version number there’s a pom and a jar file, but these file names are something like “common-api-1.0.jar” and “common-api-1.0.pom”.
In Gradle, I tried to reference version 1.0 like this:
implementation(group: 'com.group1’, name: 'common-api', version: '1.0')

This fails with an error indicating that it couldn’t resolve the dependency on the Artifactory server at  “/com/group1/common-api/1.0/common-api-1.0.pom”.
That makes sense because on Artifactory it’s located at “/com/group1/api/1.0/common-api-1.0.pom”.
So I tried to reference the dependency like this:
implementation(group: 'com.group1’, name: 'api', version: '1.0')

That also fails as the build tries to find “/com/group1/api/1.0/api-1.0.pom”. Since the pom file is called “common-api-1.0.pom”, it can’t find it.
Is there any way to get Gradle to find these dependencies, or do the dependencies need to be republished to Artifactory so that they follow the expected naming convention?

It doesn't look easy. You can have ivy repos (unlike maven ones) with a unique pattern (docs), but Ivy repos don't support POMs natively (ie no POM option here), despite what the documentation claims. Given the misleading docs, it might be worth asking Gradle.

We ended up republishing a bunch of jars with Gradle because we couldn't find a workaround. Alternatively, we could have renamed the jars to match the module names and republished with Ivy, but we found that when we got to some that included test jars, those had a different naming convention expected by Gradle, too, and renaming wasn't a fix.
At least it was a few dozen jars rather than hundreds or something.
